# How to convert a year (with comma) into Year,Month and Days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some values that represent years.
For example 37,8 years.
I want to convert it in SQL Oracle to Three columns:

- Year: 37
- Month: 9
- Days: 18

How can I do that in my query?

Comment: Perhaps a little late now, but what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
select 
  trunc(n) as years
 ,to_char(date'2020-01-01' + mod(n,1)*365, 'mm') as months
 ,to_char(date'2020-01-01' + mod(n,1)*365, 'dd') as days
from (select 37.8 n from dual);
```

```
YEARS   MONTHS  DAYS
37      10      19
```

Comment: You're too kind.

Comment: But subtract 1 from both generated dates, to account for adding onto day 1, before converting to strings? Or use the last day of a year as the fixed point.

Comment: Why? There is no month 0 and day 0, so what if you add just 37.0 years? I'm not sure, that's better to ask OP

Comment: That's what I mean - 37.0 would give 37 1 1, not 37 0 0. Actually my fix is wrong too; subtracting 1 from days after converting to string would work for that instead, but the months is maybe tricker; though doing the same for that would give the result in the question. ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=de22d2f647a87536512621ee3b612cdb)). Which makes sense is up to the OP, as you say, but if it's supposed to represent years, months and days rather than a date, the calendar not having a month zero doesn't seem to matter. Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXTRACT` to get the values:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR  FROM dt ) - 1970 AS years,
       EXTRACT( MONTH FROM dt ) - 1 AS months,
       EXTRACT( DAY   FROM dt ) - 1 AS days
FROM   (
  SELECT DATE '1970-01-01' + 37.8 * 365.25 AS dt
  FROM   DUAL
)
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> YEARS | MONTHS | DAYS
> ----: | -----: | ---:
>    37 |      9 |   19
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=91c32a75b6e2eb5b486f4358eb62ba1c)*